# Why ∫ dn is = N?

Tags: integration, notation, indefinite-integrals

Maybe a simple question here but I was wondering how $\int \, dn=N$?

I understand if you integrate say 1 in terms of $X$ you get $X$ but if you integrate $0$ how does that equal $X$ or $N$ in this case.

To give you further context I am doing this question. I got it right but I guessed which is never good because I don't see how integrating nothing gets me that.

[image]

Here is what the Mark Scheme says:
[image]

Comment: Who's integrating $0$ here?

Comment: The mark scheme is. I have edited the question.

Comment: The symbol $\displaystyle \small{\int \mathrm dn}$ is an abbreviation of $\displaystyle \small{\int \mathbf{1}\mathrm dn}$ where $\bf 1$ is the map $n\mapsto 1$.

Comment: $\int dN=\int (1)dN$

Comment: Oh I see, so when I solve the differential eqution and write dn the one is already there so whwn I intergrate it I get N?

Comment: What is the "Mark Scheme"?

Comment: You should be careful about $n$ vs. $N$. In mathematics the two are always considered to be two separate variables. Your mixing of the two just makes things more confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int_0^N dn=\int_0^N (1) dn=\int_0^N (n^0) dn=\left[n^1/1\right]^N_0=N-0=N$$